# Python django query database and get all FKs in list

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, foreign-keys

I am new in django and I am working in order to implement a Rest API.  My issue is with a query that I can't find a working solution no matter the number of hours spent on it.  More specifically I have these two models:

```
class Subcategory(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, db_column='category')

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
```

As you can see each category has one or more subcategories and in the subcategory model I have a foreign key to the category.  What i want to do is to query my database, get all categories and to each category add an extra field subcategories with a list of the subcategories.  My idea it was to follow the FKs using .select_related but it seems to be a wrong solution since I am taking the following error:

```
"message": "name 'subcategory__category' is not defined"
```

My query is:

```
Category.objects.all().select_related(subcategory__category).values()
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue and find a way to implement my query?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Do it like this**

```
class Category(models.Model):

   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
   image = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None) 
   sub_cat = ManyToManyField(Subcategory, blank=True)

class Subcategory(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):   
       return self.name
```

**Now,query part**

```
temp = []
all_cat = Category.objects.all()
for cat in all_cat:
  temp.append( list(cat.sub_cat.all()) )
```

I think this is what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! The problem is that one category may have one or more subcategories so with adding the Foreign key in category I don't have this capability

Comment: Then you should add ManytoMany in your category!is that okay?

Comment: I see, and how the query will be?